# Can only create one Personal view in Document Libraries? SP2010

Tags: bug, document-library

It seems only one personal view can be created in each Document library?

(Once one personal view has been created, you can still go through the process of creating more personal views, the new view names appear in your ‘Views’ list, though when you select one of your latter views, the view defaults to the very first personal view you created, though with properties of the latter view, losing all initial views properties).

This is a know bug with Microsoft so was wondering if anyone else has come across this and if there is a workaround?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there's a [workaround](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sharepoint2010general/thread/744a13dc-8bb6-45c0-abef-9b94fe0a90fc): Sort columns in the views. However I can't reproduce that and always get the erratic behavior. You can see the correct view if you click the "List" Tab and check the dropdown that contains all the views. There the correct view is displayed.